# The name 'next' cannot be found

Tags: angular, typescript

estoy haciendo un CRUD en angular usando laravel y no puedo ingresar los datos de la base de datos a la tabla aunque me aparecen bien por consola. mi codigo esta de la siguiente manera...

**home.component.ts**

```html
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Laptop } from '../interfaces/laptop';
import { LaptopsService} from '../services/laptops.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  API_ENDPOINT = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api';
  laptops: Laptop[] = [];
  constructor(private laptopService: LaptopsService, private httpClient: HttpClient) { 
    httpClient.get(this.API_ENDPOINT + '/laptops').subscribe(next: (data: Laptop[]) =>{
     this.laptops = data;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

mientras que en la tabla ingreso los datos con un *ngFor de la siguiente manera...

**home.component.html**

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead class="table-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NOMBRE</th>
        <th>CIUDAD</th>
        <th>CARGO</th>
        <th>EQUIPO ASIGNADO</th>
        <th>FECHA DE ENTREGA</th>
        <th>MODELO</th>
        <th>AÑO</th>
        <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
        <th>IMAGEN DEL EQUIPO</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let laptop of laptops">
        <td>{{laptop.nombre}}</td>
        <td>{{laptop.ciudad}}</td>
        <td>{{laptop.cargo}}</td>
        <td>{{laptop.equipo_asignado}}</td>
        <td>{{laptop.fecha_entrega}}</td>
        <td>{{laptop.modelo}}</td>
        <td>{{laptop.año}}</td>
        <td>{{laptop.descripcion}}</td>
        <td>{{laptop.imagen}}</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

que podría hacer en este caso?

Comment: El código como texto.

Comment: En este caso podrías leer [ask] y hacer el [tour], o haber leído el mensaje que aparece antes de hacer tu primera pregunta, porque si no se siguen unas reglas las preguntas acaban con votos negativos y cerradas. Te recomiendo que edites la pregunta y pongas el código como texto antes de que eso suceda.

Comment: Por favor traduce el título de la pregunta. Entra a [edit] y cambia también las imágenes por código.

Comment: listo ya cambie la imagen por codigo